# Set network share quota using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-server

I don't have experience with Microsoft FSRM and in my quest in finding a solution to my question, I couldn't find one; maybe it's out there but I just could find it.

I have multiple folders in my network share. Let's say the root share is `\\1.2.3.4\Shares` and below it got the following shared folders:

`HR` with `10G` of used space

`IT` with `20G` of used space

`Security` with `5G` of used space

What I need to achieve is set a `15G` additional size as the hard quota for each folder. So

`HR` will become `25G` of hard quota

`IT` will become `35G` of hard quota

`Security` will become `20G` of hard quota

File server is running on Windows 2016 Standard. Appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Is [Set-FsrmQuota](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/fileserverresourcemanager/Set-FsrmQuota?view=win10-ps) what you are looking for ?

Comment: It turns out I needed to use New-FsrmQuota. Thank you @Swisstone